# running convert command on cloud-functions returns error that I cannot reproduce locally

Tags: imagemagick, google-cloud-functions

Given this code:
```

```
let exec = require('child-process-promise').exec
let magickCommand = `convert -background none -stroke "rgba(139, 184, 232, 1)" -fill "rgba(136, 183, 232, 0.83)" -font /tmp/1057522377634683-priceFont.ttf -pointsize 70 label:"$48" -trim ( +clone -background "rgba(135, 138, 140, 0.59)" -shadow 80x8+8+10 ) +swap -background none -layers merge +repage -rotate 0 -fuzz 10% -trim /tmp/1057522377634683-priceText.png`
exec(magickCommand).then(() => { console.log('finished') })
```

```
I can run locally on my Windows machine with matched version of `convert` as is on google-cloud-functions: ImageMagick-6.8.9-9-Q16-x64-static

when I run the same Imagemagick command on functions I get the following error:
```

```
{ ChildProcessError: Command failed: convert -background none -stroke "rgba(139, 184, 232, 1)" -fill "rgba(136, 183, 232, 0.83)" -font /tmp/1057522377634683-priceFont.ttf -pointsize 90 label:"$48" -trim \( -clone -background "rgba(135, 138, 140, 0.59)" -shadow 80x8+8+10 \) +swap -background none -layers merge +repage -rotate 0 -fuzz 10% -trim /tmp/1057522377634683-priceText.png
convert: image sequence is required `-clone' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/967.
 `convert -background none -stroke "rgba(139, 184, 232, 1)" -fill "rgba(136, 183, 232, 0.83)" -font /tmp/1057522377634683-priceFont.ttf -pointsize 90 label:"$48" -trim \( -clone -background "rgba(135, 138, 140, 0.59)" -shadow 80x8+8+10 \) +swap -background none -layers merge +repage -rotate 0 -fuzz 10% -trim /tmp/1057522377634683-priceText.png` (exited with error code 1)
    at callback (/user_code/node_modules/child-process-promise/lib/index.js:33:27)
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:211:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:342:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:497:12)
  name: 'ChildProcessError',
  code: 1,
  childProcess: 
   { ChildProcess: { [Function: ChildProcess] super_: [Object] },
     fork: [Function],
     _forkChild: [Function],
     exec: [Function],
     execFile: [Function],
     spawn: [Function],
     spawnSync: [Function: spawnSync],
     execFileSync: [Function: execFileSync],
     execSync: [Function: execSync] },
  stdout: '',
  stderr: 'convert: image sequence is required `-clone\' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/967.\n' }
```

```
I have tried the command with and without ('s in the functions environment but either way the command exec still fails. With function deployment taking 15 to 20 minutes - debugging this is terribly slow and I'm at my wits end. I'm hoping someone has ran into something like this in the past and can see the error in my ways.

Node version locally and in google-cloud-functions is 6.11.2

When I run the command locally I do generate a transparent .png file
[Google Drive folder with font and output .png file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5rLx2EOQ89zOFhYZkdTWUpsZTA)

Comment: I get the same error (on Linux) if I replace `label:"$48"` by `label:` (i.e. nothing is generated). Given the starting '$', it is possible that the `$48` is interpreted as variable name somewhere and yields an empty string. Not hard to check by temporarily replacing/removing the `$`. In which case the solution would be to escape the `$`: `\$` (perhaps).

Comment: Hi @xenoid - I get the error with just plain text too. I just pulled one of the functions out as an example - so with the above same code when writing a label:"Nicole" I get the same error on cloud-functions environment. But I'm going to try your suggestion all the same...can't hurt :) I'll get back to you in about 20 minutes, once the function gets deployed.

Comment: I don't know functions so I can't help much more. Maybe also remove all the drop-shadow generation and check that an image is indeed generated in the first stage.

Comment: @xenoid - You, Sir, are a steely-eyed missile man! That $ was the issue...and now I'm off to the next one ;) If you'd be so inclined to write this as an answer I'll happily accept it. I owe you a beer my friend! Reach out to me with a wishlist link or something!

Comment: Done. Actually when I tried your command on Linux, the generated image only had the `8`. Not hard to figure out why the $4 has disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same error (on Linux) if I replace label:"$48" by label: (i.e. nothing is generated). Given the starting '$', it is possible that the $48 is interpreted as variable name somewhere and yields an empty string. Not hard to check by temporarily replacing/removing the $. In which case the solution would be to escape the $: \$ (perhaps).